# Rails4 handle GET Model and Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I'm trying to  find a document depending on the get param.

Rails 4.0.0

Ruby 2.0.0

mongoid

Controller : search_controller.rb

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
 def search
  @search = params[:q]
  @result = Search.find_event(@search)
 end
end
```

Model : search.rb

```
class Search
 include Mongoid::Document

 def find_event(string)
    events.find_by(location : string)
 end     
end
```

SyntaxError in SearchController#search

```
app/models/search.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' events.find_by(location : string) ^
```

ps : I'm new to rails , i appreciate to any answer which improve my understanding for rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a space before the colon when passing a Hash to a method. Change it to:

```
events.find_by(location: string)
```